# Trouble getting a value from an array Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to set the post_id as a variable using the following but I'm getting an Undefined index error.

```
$propertyID['post_id']
```

This is my var_dump()

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "4323"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(9) "unique_id"
  }
}
```

Comment: use **$propertyID[0]['post_id']**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$propertyID[0]['post_id']`

Answer (score 0):

All value in index 0 of array :-

```
$propertyID[0]['post_id'] //result :- 4323
$propertyID[0]['meta_key'] //result :- unique_id
```